# moving data from redis to postgres (db writes every couple of seconds per connected device)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, redis, postgis

Devices connected to my server send their current geo position every couple of seconds over tcp. This geo data (lng lat timestamp etc) is now being persisted in redis, however I need to be able to move this data from Redis to Postgres (can skip Redis writes for this particular feature if there's another way) in order to make proper use of geo queries. (In this particular case how many devices are < 50km from point X (just btw other parts of the app are making use of geofencing etc).

I wanted to avoid writing to Postgres (with Postgis) every 5 seconds (atm we got dozens of devices, potentialy (and probably) this number will increase to thousands). I was thinking about scheduling a worker which would update positions of devices which sent data within every 5 minutes - this would solve my problem but it feels hacky and there has to be a better solution. I assumed that I should be worried about getting 100x writes a second to a Postgres db.

Did any of you face a similar problem? I'm lookin for any pointers on how could I debounce those writes to happen like once per 1 or 3 minutes.

Comment: You may still write to Redis as a write cache, and continuously move data from Redis to PG incrementally. So in Redis you have the latest position if needed, without give up the high number of positions you receive per minute, but at the same time you can make complex queries in PG. To move data incrementally there are several options. One is SCAN, another is to populate a sorted set at each write, with element_to_update,unix_timestamp as value,score.

Comment: It's actually quite practical to write a few hundred times a second to PostgreSQL, you just need to `SET synchronous_commit = off` in your transactions and/or have fast write-back caching storage. The bigger issue is that if you write direct to PostgreSQL it's a pain if you want to do any maintenance that may require exclusive locks or a restart, so it makes a lot of sense to accumulate into something like Redis as a buffer anyway.

Comment: @antirez sorted sets with timestamp as a score are awesome! using them to create routes :)

Comment: I started writing a custom logic using redis pubsub/expiration/scan, but then i found your answer @CraigRinger, thanks! I did now know what I should've known, you rock!